# Travel from Greece to Horsens Denmark

Tags: greece, denmark, copenhagen

I'm planning to travel to Horsens Denmark on July for two weeks. I've seen there are no airports there and the nearest airports are in Billund Airport (58km), Aarhus Airport (90km) and Karup Airport (103km) *although there aren't any frequent flights for the last two or not at all*. Another option I've seen is to travel to Copenhagen and from there to Horsens by train.

Are there any other/better ways to reach Horsens? And which would you suggest?
Are there any additional informations that I should know?

Comment: Can you define what is frequent enough for you? There seem to be daily flights to Billund from Frankfurt, Amsterdam etc.

Comment: @uncovery I was referring to the last two airports.I mean daily. I must remind you I'm flying from Greece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get there by also by bus (check [Eurolines](http://eurolines.com)) or train, but the best options are the ones you already mentioned.

I wouldn't recommend taking a bus. It would be a very long and tiring bus ride all the way from Greece. You would have to change buses since there is no direct bus line. And the price is unlikely to be much better than flying.

Taking the train is a possibility but also very time consuming, you would probably have to change trains multiple times.  It is likely to be much more expensive than flying.

I would recommend to you, if you are unable to get any reasonable flights to the nearby airports, to opt to fly to Copenhagen and take the train from there to Horsens. Anyway, you are more likely to find a good deal and a direct flight to Copenhagen (from Athens at least). The train ride is smooth, takes typically less than 3 hours, normal price without seat reservation: 362 DKR. The trains are fairly frequent, usually one per hour, except during night. Check [DSB](http://www.dsb.dk/) or the [Journey Planner](http://www.rejseplanen.dk/bin/query.exe/en) (in English) for timetables/prices and further info.

If you have a car you could of course also drive there yourself, but it's hardly worth it for one person (fuel costs, extra time spent driving). Only maybe if you were planning to do a lot of travelling around once you are there.

Comment: No need for Google translate as English is available.

Comment: As it is now the "English version" of the DSB web page pretty much useless for tourists. Seems more to be geared towards potential investors. Their trip search interface and price info are only shown in Danish.

Comment: Fair enough, strange why they would do that though.